# Convert SQL Server DateTimeOffset to Time Zone

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible in a SQL Server Query to convert a datetimeoffset to it's corresponding timezone?  For example, I have values stored as:

2015-01-03 00:30 -06:00

2015-01-10 00:30 -05:00

I want my sql query to display -06:00 as CST or CDT and -05:00 as EST or EDT if daylight savings is in effect.

I'm coding an RSS Feed where I ultimately want my result set column to display:

Fri, 02 Jan 2015 18:30 CST

Fri, 09 Jan 2015 18:30 EST

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why is -06:00 CST? It could be any of a number of valid time zones. Are you wanting only US time zones? You could use DATEPART(TZoffest, YourDate) and a case expression.

Comment: SQL Server does not provide any built-in function that returns the time zone name of a DateTimeOffset.  You either need to create such a function or do the formatting on the consuming application.

Comment: @wdosanjos this doesn't need a function. If there are only the US time zones a simple case expression can handle this easily.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I will have international time entries/offsets so I want to be able to display the offset as the corresponding time zone name. Should I make a time zone table where the offset is the key extracting the offset and do a join?

Comment: @behofmann the solution is more complex, because you need to take into account daylight saving time rules across the different time zones.

Comment: @behofmann note that daylight saving time rules change over time, so a precise algorithm must take that into account to handle prior date/time correctly.

Comment: I have a location table that has a foreign key to a primary key in a time zone table. With this, I can get the time zone name associated with a location.

Comment: My entries are stored with a datetimeoffset column based on GMT. When thinking about CST Daylight Savings (DST) for example, the offset changes by 60 minutes, BUT the time doesn't change. Subtracting 60 minutes for DST from GMT would give me the wrong time. As I see it now, I simply would be changing the time zone name from CST to CDT. Am I thinking correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do this using DATEPART. If you need more time zones then you might need to use a lookup table and join on the value of DATEPART. Keep in mind though that there are multiple timezones for each offset. Those would vary by latitude.

```
create table #TimeZoneExample
(
    MyDateTimeOffset datetimeoffset
)

insert #TimeZoneExample
select '2015-01-03 00:30 -06:00' union all
select '2015-01-10 00:30 -05:00'

select convert(datetime, MyDateTimeOffset) as PostDate
    , case DATEPART(TZoffset, MyDateTimeOffset)/60 
        when -5 then 'EST'
        when -6 then 'CST'
        when -7 then 'MST'
        when -8 then 'PST'
        else 'Unknown Time Zone'
    end
from #TimeZoneExample

drop table #TimeZoneExample
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not take into account daylight saving time.

Comment: Good point @wdosanjos and of course it would be nearly impossible to do this even close given the provided example information because not all locations/countries/states use daylight saving time. You would need to expand this considerably to accommodate international times as suggested. And any accurate result would require considerable more information than just the datetimeoffset. You would need to know the location also so you can determine accurate time. Not sure if 100% is needed here but certainly worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to work on this, I realized that the only option that really works is to save all date/times as UTC, and include a timezone indicator that ties to a table showing when any time zone changes, such as daylight savings time, occurs. This will require custom code for your data.

Fortunately, someone maintains a database of timezone data including DST transitions and the like - the [IANA Time Zone DB](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). You can use and update the raw data yourself, or look around for other examples of how to do this, including the [SQL Server Timezone Support Project](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) on GitHub.

In the end, UTC, Timezone, and a conversion database is the only way to ensure perfect accuracy AND convertability of times between time zones - especially those rare TZs that are 15 minutes or 1/2 hour shifts from UTC.